# htaccess rewrite rule with length of request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have the code

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  index.php
```

which will redirect all the request to the index.php

I want to check if the request have 16 character then want to redirect to `index.php?param=ABCDEFGHJK123456`

If length of request is not 16 character the just `index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.{16})$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]{16})$ index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]`